# sockets programming with android, port forwarding?

Tags: android, sockets, port

If I am sending messages from one android phone to another and both Android phones are connected to wifi, using sockets programming do I need to set port forwarding on my router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## No

if they are on the same WiFi/Network.

### If the two phones are on different networks

Port Forwarding needs to be done. It is usually with a router in between.

***Common Use Cases:***

- You're accessing a commonly used port on a computer which is not publicly visible. Eg: You're hosting a webserver hence port 80 is used but you also want to use the same port on a different machine. Then you would say forward port 8080 and map it to the other computer's port 80.
- You have a firewall/proxy which allows communication on only a few port ranges.